# Tabulator table: Change font

Tags: tabulator

I'm trying to use the Tabulator table. Changing theme (including different .css), I get new background and foreground colors but the font is always times new roman. How do I change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
.tabulator {
  font-family: "Courier New";
}
```